# Windows Server 2008 with Windows 98 clients login issues

Tags: windows-server-2008, authentication, windows

I have just purchased a new server running windows 2008 and have set up active directory with a new domain name.As the existing domain name was running a win2000 server

I am runing  a ms-sql database server on the win 2008 server and need win 98 machines also to access it

However i am am uable to log into the win2008 server.

any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you'll need to install DSCLIENT on the '98 client to pull this off, as well as a few other requirements below.  The server will need to be running WINS.

[MSKB555038](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555038) - pasting in the most germane bits, in case MS decides to rewire their KBs again at some point.

**Windows 98/ME**

1. Install Internet Explorer 6 with Service Pack 1 or higher.
2. Install DSCLIENT utility from Windows 2000 Server installation disk or from

   http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;288358

Note: Please review the knowlagebase: "Directory Services Client Update for Windows 98" 323455:

```
 http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;323455
```

3. Enable NTLM 2 Authentication (please see "More Information" section for details).
4. Enable SMB Signing (please see "More Information" section for details).
5. Configure the workstation to use local WINS server.
6. Consider installing the hotfixes that descrive in:

   Service Packs and Hotfixes That Are Available to Resolve Account Lockout Issues

   http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;817701
7. Configure the local DNS domain as DNS under TCP/IP properties.

Note: If you are using Windows 95, please follow the knowlagebase bellow:
http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;%5BLN%5D;811497

Note: If the logon problem is'nt resolved, please review the following knowlagebase:

Problems logging on to a Windows 2000-based server or a Windows 2003-based server
http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?kbid=272594

**Servers side:**

1. Configure each server in the domain to use local WINS server.
2. If you are using Windows 2000 or higher DHCP server, make sure that the DHCP can register old clients.
3. Review: KB 898060

   http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/898060

Note: Some articles recommend to disable SMB sign in the domain controller OU. Please avoid changing domain
          controllers policy, and specialy dont disable  SMB sign.

Note: Windows 98/ME clients have problem with computer names largers then eight characters. Please avoid
          using long computer names.